# Array counting with different keys

Tags: php, arrays, math, multidimensional-array

What I need is putting this array in a loop, but I can't get it to work because week is 1 - 9 and the key is 0 - 8. So i getting a error with a undefined offset i know why the does that but I don't know how to do this properly.

Before people ask me why not just change week1 to week0 and start counting from there. I can't because I did a calculating that is based on 1 - 52 and it will mess up my calculating if I start on 0 - 51

```
$totaal_vruchtzetting_week[10] = $totaal["week1"][0] + // = 0.46
                                 $totaal["week2"][1] + // = 2.87
                                 $totaal["week3"][2] + // = 4.97
                                 $totaal["week4"][3] + // = 4.35
                                 $totaal["week5"][4] + // = 3.02
                                 $totaal["week6"][5] + // = 2.03
                                 $totaal["week7"][6] + // = 1.41
                                 $totaal["week8"][7] + // = 1.12
                                 $totaal["week9"][8];  // = 1.13

                                 // Should be total 21,36
```

Edit:
This is my loop I got until now but it gives me the wrong answer plus 2 errors

```
    for($week = 1; $week < 9; $week++)
    {
        for($sw = 0; $sw <= 8; $sw++)
        {
            $totaal_vruchtzetting_week[10] += $totaal["week".$week][$sw];
        }
    }



echo $totaal_vruchtzetting_week[10]; // Outputs 170.89
```

Comment: Can you show your loop?

Comment: Can't you just try for loop or for each loop staring with **$i=1** and use $i variable as a part of offset. i.e. **$totaal["week".$i][$i-1]** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sum with this this loop

```
$i = 1;
$result = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    if (isset($totaal['week' . $i]) && isset($totaal['week' . $i][$i - 1])) {
            $result += floatval($totaal['week' . $i][$i - 1]);
    }
}

$totaal_vruchtzetting_week[10] = $result;
```

Comment: I have edited the function. I have to use floatval instead of intval

Comment: Hi, this works. Can u explain what u did because i dont understand whats happening

Comment: The cycle `for($sw = 0; $sw <= 8; $sw++)` performs on elements from 0 to 8 of each $totaal items. This means that the script execute `$totaal['week1'][0] + $totaal['week1'][1] + $totaal['week1'][2] + $totaal['week1'][3] + $totaal['week1'][4] + ...`. All this indexes are undefined, so PHP print warnings.

Answer (score 2):

```
$i=1;
$totaal_vruchtzetting_week[10]=0;
foreach($totaal as $total)
{
 $totaal_vruchtzetting_week[10]+=$total["week$i"][$i-1];
 $i++;
}
echo $totaal_vruchtzetting_week[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach(array_values($totaal) as $index=>$item)
    $sum += reset($item); 
echo $sum; // 21.36    
$totaal_vruchtzetting_week[10] = $sum;
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/uAI2U)

Comment: I getting output 24.00

Comment: mm dont know if i put youre code in a seperate php file im getting 21.36 so thats good.

Comment: Im confused, when i put it im my php file im getting 24.00 as output. But when i put it in a seperate file im getting 21.36 wich is good

Comment: @Julez hmm... try wrap  $sum += floatval(reset($item));

Comment: @Julez forgot about floatval. Just, you say that in one file $sum=24, but in another file $sum = 21.36? Yes? What in first file (where = 24 )?

Comment: Do you have skype or something ? so i can explain better

Comment: @Julez its impossble. See fiddle.

Comment: Yes i know but somewhere something is going wrong and i cant find where. if you have skype i can send you the file if you want

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question, but did you consider `foreach`? It iterates over every array regardless of the keys.